# Waist bone won't move. Only rotates in place

Tags: animation, rigging

The bone I used to control my character's upper body is stuck in place and only rotates when I try to move it.

From what I checked, it is not the same problem as this question:
[In Pose mode, my bones are stuck in rotate, and wont transform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5241/in-pose-mode-my-bones-are-stuck-in-rotate-and-wont-transform/5254#5254)

Yes, clearing the parenting to the root bone solves it, but that is not what I want and from all the models I've done before, this is the first it happened.
Here is the model:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Okp_8X219XU0s2Zk1Nb280SkE

Any ideas?

Comment: It's solve thanks to Vectorius. I removed the model from the link since it's from a personal project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its is related,  actually, since your *Main* bone is acting like the last bone in a connected chain

Enter *Edit Mode*, select the *Belly* bone and go to its *Bone Data Panel* to uncheck *Connected*. Do the same for the *Hips* bone. Now you can translate the *Main* bone in *Pose Mode*

[image: panel]

Comment: you saved me :D